# FailedConnectionException2 occuring frequently using network-wreq

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I'm running a bot to play at `vindinium.org`. It sits running in shell loop so that when it's finished a new game starts.

I've noticed though, that probably half of my games are being lost to exceptions being thrown somewhere in `http-conduit`. The exception is 
`vindinium: FailedConnectionException2 "vindinium.org" 80 False getAddrInfo: does not exist (Name or service not known)`

As I understand, that's a DNS failure, but I'm not sure what causes it, and other people on the same network as me don't have this problem (but nobody else has haskell client).

Currently, the only code I have that deals with network is:

```
vinPost :: String -> [FormParam] -> IO Resp
vinPost url body = catch (post url (body ++ ["key" := vindinKey]) >>= asJSON)
                   (\e -> do
                            let err = show (e :: IOException)
                            hPutStr stderr $ "Error: " ++ err
                            vinPost url body)
```

Originally, I didn't have the `catch` part either, but I tried adding it and it didn't help. It literally just tries again because the error seems fleeting.

Anyway, why is my catch block failing to catch the exception, and what's causing this exception?

Comment: I think you are only catching `e :: IOException`, ignoring exceptions of other types. Try adding a catch for whatever the type of `FailedConnectionException2` is.

Comment: It's an `HttpException`. IIRC, that exception can also be thrown if you're out of file descriptors.